# Cannot modify header information

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Headers already sent by PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/headers-already-sent-by-php)

My problem is that I have a class with a function inside of it, and I get;

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/user/public_html/inc/class.php:105) in /home/user/public_html/inc/facebook/login.php on line 21
```

When the page I'm using it on redirects a user with the header(); tag. The class is;

```
class mysql {
private $user;
private $pass;
private $db;

public function __construct($user1, $pass1, $db1) {
    $this->user = $user1;
    $this->pass = $pass1;
    $this->db = $db1;
    $this->connect();
}

public function connect() {
    $this->connection = mysql_connect('localhost', $this->user, $this->pass);
    $select = mysql_select_db($this->db, $this->connection);
}

public function query($x) {
    return mysql_query($x);
}

public function fetch($x) {
    return mysql_fetch_array($x);
}

public function num($x) {
    return mysql_num_rows($x);
}
}
```

Line 105 is the;

```
return mysql_fetch_array($x);
```

And the file trying to do the header redirect just includes this file at the top of the page and does the header lower down.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This error usually happens when you call `headers` after outputting data (eg `echo`, `print`).

Comment: Your problem is that you want to redirect someone (using header) while there is already output written. After output is written, headers can't be changed anymore.

Comment: If you're using closing php tags (`?>`) at the end of your class definition, check for a newline or any other whitespace character after that. If that's the problem, I'd advice you to not use closing tags in class/function files.

Comment: The class you described doesn't render any output, so I don't see how you would get a header error. Can you add some of the page that loads the class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When the page I'm using it on redirects a user with the header(); tag. The class is;

That's the problem.  You need to put `ob_start();` right at the beginning of the file with `header();`.

Comment: This is definitely not a correct answer per se. The symptoms of his problem might disappear but the cause probably lies in his architecture

Comment: Well, it does, but it works.  (in case you don't know: something outputs stuff before the `header()`, when it shalln't.)

Comment: Hiding error messages is the way to get bigger errors in the future. Meanwhile, the correct answer gets downvoted.

Comment: @Kwpolska I know, but it does not learn him anything. Just output buffering everything is not a solution.

Comment: @Kwpolska while `ob_start();` might work for you, but i agree with hoppa, this is not the correct way. now the error you are getting is because the header is being sent after the echo which throws an error in php, now to avoid this i would suggest, do not use `header()` in your class. if you want to redirect using PHP always Put the `header();` on top of your page.

Comment: @Ibrahim ...unless you have to check some stuff (like `if(loggedIn()) header('Location: foo.php');`

Comment: it depends, for rest there is javascript and html <a href> redirect :)

Comment: My header redirect isn't at the top of the page, it's in an IF statement.

Comment: But what happens before the `if`?  If any output (`echo`, ...) happens before the `if`, it won't work.  `$foo='bar';if($foo=='bar') header(...);` would work, though.

Comment: There is no output before it.

Comment: That's a problem...  Try stuff from Treffynnon's post.

Answer (score 8):

### What is triggering this error?

This error is triggered when some code has already output to the "screen" before you call the header function. Headers must be set before you output anything.

See the description from the [`header()` PHP manual page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php):

> Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is
>   sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP.
>   It is a very common error to read code with include(), or require(),
>   functions, or another file access function, and have spaces or empty
>   lines that are output before header() is called. The same problem
>   exists when using a single PHP/HTML file.

### I am not outputting anything so what gives?

I would say that your code is generating an error somewhere. Try setting:

```
ini_set('display_errors', true);
ini_set('error_reporting', ~0);
```

In your index.php file as the very first set of commands.

Another possibility is that something somewhere is outputting a space or line return character. You cannot have **any** output of **any** kind before you call the `header()` function.

### Possible solutions

There are two ways to fix this.

1. Use output buffering to catch anything that might be echoed before you have set your headers
2. Stop the code from outputting anything prematurely although this is a little more brittle

#### Option 1

To implement solution 1 you would put a call to [`ob_start()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) at the very beginning of your code (at the top of your bootstrap file or index.php usually).

Then once all logic has been completed and you are ready to output you would call [`ob_end_flush()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-end-flush.php) to output everything in the buffer. Usually this would be at the very end of your index.php or bootstrap file.

#### Option 2

Zend Framework has the following in their coding guidelines to help mitigate the accidental output of new lines and spaces. See http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/coding-standard.php-file-formatting.html#coding-standard.php-file-formatting.general:

> For files that contain only PHP code, the closing tag ("?>") is never permitted. It is not required by PHP, and omitting it´ prevents the accidental injection of trailing white space into the response.

Comment: This is incorrect. OP's error comes from the fact that he is outputting data and later calling `header`.

Comment: I agree. Otherwise, a return statement prints nothing.

Comment: ... and, most likely, the error is an invalid MySQL call: none of the mysql_...() calls check the return value.

Comment: If there is an error it would generate output causing the header error. So his suggestion is not wrong at all.

Comment: If the code would generate an error, there shall be no output AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

That line shouldn't output anything, so that means that output was started because a warning or notice was printed. Fix the problem.

Alternatively, you gave use the wrong source file.

Answer (score -2):

Disable wanrings on php.ini .Those are warnings , if you have access in your php.ini , modify the following

**error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED**

when in development

**display_errors = On**

when you'll be in production don't forget to

**display_errors = Off**

Don't forget to **restart apache when you change php.ini**

**I didn't say to disable errors ,disable only warnings,** 
**Cannot modify header information** means you have outputed something before the header.remove all spaces before header();

Comment: Bad, bad idea.  Error reporting shall be always on.  What if something breaks?  He will not know about anything, the website or mysql queries can work incorrectly.

Comment: I want to fix the error, not cover it up.